# Srcset using sitecore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, sitecore, sitecore8

I have 1176px X 820px image. It should render 1140px X 290px using sitcore srcset option. I am using the following code but it does not work properly.

```
Dictionary<int, int> wList = new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 150, 768 }, { 230, 1024 }, { 290, 2000 } };

var withQuerystring = string.Empty;

foreach (var v in wList)
{
    var s = Model.ASpot1Image.Src + "?h=" + v.Key;
    var r = Sitecore.Resources.Media.HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(s);
    withQuerystring = withQuerystring + r + " " + v.Value + "w,";
}

withQuerystring = withQuerystring.TrimEnd(',');

if (Model.ASpot1ImageUrl != null)
{
    using (BeginRenderLink(m => Model.ASpot1ImageUrl, isEditable: true))
    {
       @RenderImage(m => m.ASpot1Image, new { @class = "img-responsive", 
       @srcset = @withQuerystring }, isEditable: true)
```

Comment: What is not working? images are not resizing correctly? or sitecore is not adding srcset to the image?

Comment: Image are not resizing correctly. The desire resolution I am not getting, I am thinking that is because of image aspect ratio.

Comment: can you post the HTML output you are getting for the image element?

Comment: Don't forget the media hash which is used for [Media Request Protection.](https://blog.najmanowicz.com/2015/05/15/do-not-turn-sitecore-media-request-protection-off-and-protect-older-sitecore-versions-with-imageguard/). Without the correct hash the image will not be resized. Do not turn it off, it's done for a reason!

Comment: Related: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5410/how-can-i-make-responsive-images-editable/5411